# Separate class and instance in different modules in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In one module, I define a class:

```hs
class Monad m => MonadTime m where
    currentTime :: m UTCTime
```

The `MonadTime` is exported.

In the different module, I wanted to create an instance:

```hs
-- MonadTime is imported

instance MonadTime IO where
    currentTime :: IO UTCTime
    currentTime = Data.Time.Clock.getCurrentTime
```

However, the issue is:

> ‘currentTime’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘MonadTime’

If I move the instance to the first module, where class is defined, everything works. But my idea was to provide the implementation in main module.

How should I resolve this?

Comment: Note, though, that this is an [orphan instance](https://wiki.haskell.org/Orphan_instance). Since you can't define a `MonadTime` instance for `IO` in the same module that defines `IO`, you should define it in the module defining `MonadTime`.

Comment: @chepner this is something I am playing with - I wanted to define implementation outside of the module. The orphaned implementation dissapears when I use the new type that wraps imported. Still not sure if that make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export it with the method, so:

```
module MyModule(MonadTime(currentTime)) where

class Monad m => MonadTime m where
    currentTime :: m UTCTime
```

and in the other module:

```
module MyOtherModule where

import MyModule(MonadTime(currentTime))

instance MonadTime IO where
    currentTime :: IO UTCTime
    currentTime = Data.Time.Clock.getCurrentTime
```

Comment: Further, `module MyModule(MonadTime(..)) where` exports all the methods.